# How to create log-out script - Parse (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, parse-platform

I'm having a problem with logging out on my website. I have looked at the documentation on the parse website but it does not really provide much detail on how to log out the user, also does not help when I am not proficient with JavaScript.

When I click my log out button, it just refreshes the page and nothing more but I would like to take it back to the sign in screen.

My current script file that I have written is shown below (for obvious reasons I have removed my parse unique ids):

```
 $(function() {

    Parse.$ = jQuery;
Parse.initialize("MY CODE HERE", "MY CODE HERE");

    $('.form-logout').on('submit', function(e) {

    // Prevent Default Submit Event
    e.preventDefault();

    //logout current user
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        if (currentUser) {
            Parse.User.logout();
            window.location="Sign_In.html";
        } else {
            window.location="Sign_In.html";
        }

    });

});
```

The section where I create the button is located here in my html file:

```
<form class="form-logout" role="form">
   <input type="submit" value="Logout" id="logout" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe the method name is [`logOut()`](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-login)(Ctrl+f *"logout"*) instead of `logout()` ?

Comment: hey there thank you for the reply, however i did change it but still no luck just refreshes the page with a "?" at the end of my link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

to your page.
Then use this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    Parse.$ = jQuery;
    Parse.initialize("...", "...");

    $('.form-logout').on('submit', function (e) {
        // Prevent Default Submit Event
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("Performing submit");

        //logout current user
        if ( Parse.User.current() ) {
            Parse.User.logOut();

            // check if really logged out
            if (Parse.User.current())
                console.log("Failed to log out!");
        }

        // do redirect
        //window.location.replace("Sign_In.html");
        // or
        window.location.href = "/Sign_In.html";
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey there thank you for your reply, im still getting no luck even after the changes made. It just keeps refreshing the page, is there some sort of error log i can post and look it for more information?

Comment: Most likely page refresh on submit means that no event handler was bound to the *submit* event and it's just performing the default action. I suppose you missed some brackets or something like that. Post the code you have now and we'll have another try.

Comment: Ok, looks good. The only problem is that with this sample code ```Parse.User.current()``` will return ```null``` and thus redirect won't be executed. I updated the code so that it redirects unconditionally.

Comment: which code have u edited, is it the codepen or your original post because i tried your code again from your original post and i still dont know whats wrong, it still refreshes onlick everytime on the log out button

Comment: The code in the answer. See ```window.location.replace("Sign_In.html");``` is now out of the ```if ( Parse.User.current() ) {...}``` block. Make sure you have Sign_In.html and check the browser Console for any errors after you do the submit.

Comment: Im getting this error in the console everytime i click the log out button, http://i.gyazo.com/57c167e3aa4e520b45e9f2a24727ccfd.png. Im not to sure what that means because im not using jquery?

Comment: It means you didn't include jQuery into your page. Add something like this in your ```<header>```: ```<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>```. This must precede the inclusion of bootstrap's js.

Comment: Hey there i really appreciate all the help you have given me but the log out button doesnt seem to want to work. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVVxxd i added the jquery in but still no luck. It bring up another message saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined" but i get that with the log in system which works perfectly fine, so im not sure whats wrong with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76581/discussion-between-dekkard-and-hero8110).

Answer (score 2):

create a function

```
const handleLogout = () => {
  window.localStorage.clear();
  window.location.reload(true);
  window.location.replace('/');
};
```

then call it in this way

```
<Button className="button" onClick={() => handleLogout()}>
  <i className="fas fa-power-off"></i>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can self-execute a custom callback function on the logout() object.

That is you first wrap your `logout()` function within an anonymous function,  a syntax like:

```
function(){logout()}
```

You self execute it:

```
(function(){
logout()
})()
```

and you pass your callback as parameter!

```
(function(aFunctionIsToBePassedHere){
logout()
})(myCallbackFunction())
```

All of this become:

```
  function logout() {
    (function(myCallbackGoesHereAsVariable) {
      Parse.User.logOut();
    })(myFunctionToShowTheLoginScreen())

  }
```

and then you bind the `logout()` function to your form.